# C# Moq Entity Framework 6.1.3 Case Insensitive

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

To unit test a Entity Framework service I'm using `Moq`. The normal database uses collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` so it is not case sensitive. Is it possible to make the mocked `ApplicationDbContext` case insensitive as well?

Current code:

```
private Mock<ApplicationDbContext> GetMockedApplicationDbContext()
{
    var mockedPoliceRegion = GetMockedPoliceRegion();

    var mockContext = new Mock<ApplicationDbContext>();
    mockContext.Setup(c => c.PoliceRegions).Returns(mockedPoliceRegion.Object);

    return mockContext;
}

private Mock<DbSet<PoliceRegion>> GetMockedPoliceRegion()
{
    IQueryable<PoliceRegion> data = new List<PoliceRegion>
    {
        new PoliceRegion() {Name = "Syd"},

    }.AsQueryable();

    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<PoliceRegion>>();
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<PoliceRegion>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<PoliceRegion>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<PoliceRegion>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<PoliceRegion>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

    return mockSet;
}
```

Comment: That is an implementation concern managed by the database server and is unlikely to be reproduced locally in an isolated unit test. If you need that functionality then you would need to consider integration testing with an actual  database from the server.